# "This" vs. "The current"

Tags: word-choice, translation, demonstrative-pronouns

In Russian, when it is necessary to make a statement about some document or book in that document or book itself, it is sometimes worded like

> - "In **the current** document it is desribed how to make your cat happy."
> - instead of "In **this** document it is desribed how to make your cat happy."

Using "the current" instead of "this" is considered to be more formal.

Is it the same for English? Or we should use "this" only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In English, an active voice expression would be more natural:

> This document/book/paper describes how to keep your cat happy.

*This* is natural when a paper or treatise refers to itself.

*Current* is not only more formal, but also seems to suggest that the document is one of a series.